# Is it possible to redefine an S4 class in R?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I am working on a package that extends another package, and both of them use S4 classes and methods. More specifically, I'm working on the `sads` package, that extends Ben Bolker's `bbmle`. Our full source code is here: https://github.com/piLaboratory/sads

So far, I have successfully created new classes that extend the `mle2` S4 class from the package `bbmle`. These lines do it nicely:

```
setClass("fitsad", representation("mle2", sad="character", 
  distr="character", trunc="numeric"))
setClass("fitrad", representation("mle2", rad="character", 
  distr="character", trunc="numeric", rad.tab="rad"))
```

However, I'm not being able to cleanly **redefine** a class that was defined in `bbmle`. The class `summary.mle2` is defined in the source code for `bbmle`, but let's pretend that I need to define a new class with the same name. Adding the following line to my source code results in a weird behavior:

```
setClass("summary.mle2", representation(call = "language", 
  coef = "matrix",m2logL = "numeric", fixed="numeric"))
```

With this redefinition, the package can be loaded, and all the code works as expected. However, trying to unload the namespace results in the following cryptic error:

```
> library(sads) ## No errors here
> unloadNamespace("sads")
Error in .getClassFromCache(what, resolve.confl = "all") : 
 argument "where" is missing, with no default
> traceback()
4: .getClassFromCache(what, resolve.confl = "all")
3: .removeSuperclassBackRefs(cl, cldef, searchWhere)
2: methods::cacheMetaData(ns, FALSE, ns)
1: unloadNamespace("sads")
```

Leaving aside the question of whether we should be redefining this class or not, is this possible to do? I am sorry for not being able to present a minimal example here, but I haven't been able to reproduce this error without loading/unloading the package namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Ripped from the headlines of r{base}

`setAs(from, to, def, replace, where = topenv(parent.frame()))`

You can use this to coerce from an S4 to an S3 class

if you type `?setAs()` in the help line it should get you 90% of the way there! You can use `class()` to see if it works!

Let me know if it works for you. If you get stuck then I will do my best to help you out.